# How exactly scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve works for 3D input?

Tags: scipy, filtering, convolution

I would like to know how it calculates each element of the output (RxCxD) when the input image has shape RxCxD and the filter has shape rxcxD?

PS. I suppose to get output of size RxCx1

Comment: It's easier to think about in 2D, but it works the same way in 3D. The single value of `output[i, j, k] = np.sum(input[i:i+r, j:j+c, k:k+D] * filter)` The output size will actually be RxCxD, but you probably want to keep only a slice in the third dimension. i.e., what you maybe want is the `k = 0` slice: `convolve(input, filter)[..., 0]` since you don't seem to want to shift in the `k` dimension.

Comment: Actually, I believe you would want the `k = (D-1)//2` slice, not `k = 0`, sorry. That is: `convolve(input, filter)[..., (D-1)//2]`. The reason for this is that the `filter` starts off with its center at the origin of `input`, but you want it so that it's full overlapped (I presume) so it must be shifted in the third dimension by (roughly) half the size of the filter.

Comment: Yes, I want the fully overlapped case. Thank you for your explanation @askewchan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to think about in 2D, but it works the same way in 3D. The single value of `output[i, j, k] = np.sum(input[i:i+r, j:j+c, k:k+D] * filter)` The output size will actually be RxCxD, but you probably want to keep only a slice in the third dimension. i.e., what you maybe want is the `k = (D-1)//2` slice: `convolve(input, filter)[..., (D-1)//2]` since you don't seem to want to shift in the k dimension: i.e., taking the middle of the third dimension gives you the case with complete overlap (no shift).